# Count everything that isn't in tags with Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to count everything that isn't in tags, but failing.

The sentence: `Hi <strong>User</strong>` should return the count of `Hi User` (7)

I tried with

`(!?<[^>])^.{1,140}$`

but since I'm pretty new to Regex I can't seem to get it right!

Answer (score 0):

```
<[^>]*>|([^<>])
```

You can use this and count only the `groups` captured.That should be your result.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/25

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but I wonder; How do I, with Regex, count the characters in the groups? As I said, I'm kinda new to the Regex.

Comment: @user2687506 the no. of groups will be your answer

Comment: I guess I can't count the number of groups in Regex? Because I'm not in a programming language, so I can't use anything other than Regex.

Comment: @user2687506 regex cant return a number based on some calculation.It can only return patterns

Comment: Well, I dont need to return a number (I think). `^.{1,140}$` solves the problem with only allowing 140 characters, but I want to exclude the <tags> from the characters I'm "counting" (or what it might be called in regex).